# Having issues Running Fitnesse for projects using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fitnesse

We are having issues in running Fitnesse for  project which uses NHibernate.
For all the project FitNesse looks into appropriate folder for getting the dll.
For project having reference to NHibernate it errors saying type load exception.
Currently we have got it working by copying all the dlls into Fitnesse/dotnet folder.
I am sure there would be better way of doing this.
Can someone please help us on this!

Comment: Yes, drop Finesse and use StoryTeller.

Comment: Could you please provide some information on story teller. We would like to explore the option.

Comment: http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/08/24/how-about-a-storyteller-preview-release.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Most people make a fitnesse project within their solution that contains all of the fixtures. This project then has references to all the needed projects / dll's. Your fitnesse project itself then just needs a declaration to the classpath where everything can be found. As long as you have not coded your NHibernate configuration to a specific place, I would think you would be OK

Build, run, repeat.